# Disabled button behaving differently in windows Form

Tags: winforms

I have two button on form as:

[image: Disabled buttons]

Now when hover the portion common to both button the enabled button shows the mouse hover effect as:
[image: Disable button Mouse hover effect]

I am not sure why this is done in windows form. 
I have checked the same thing in WPF sample it works just fine, There it does not show any effect when we are on disabled button.

If we click on the portion which is common for both button the click for Enabled button is fired.

I want to know why controls have this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the disabled button in a panel or a group.  Controls aren't really meant to overlap like that, so I expect that the event handler just passes the click through to the enabled button.